# How to make photos of fruit more interesting?

Tags: image-quality, composition, ideas

What are some ideas to make fruit photos more interesting?  camera techniques I could play with? subject matter to include? ect....

Not sure if my tags are correct.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You like Froese's techniques; but, you want different techniques to try. What happened to your desire to explore his techniques? Did Froese specialize in rendering fruit? What specific technique that you think his work demonstrates did you want to perfect? Please describe the "look" that you like.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad and agree whole-heartedly with Tim and Stan. Would love to see this question morph into a photo-critique focusing on your questions and how your answers to Stan's would impact that.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question: still-life (often flowers or a bowl of fruit on a table) is a classic setting for a painting, but not so common for photos. Makes me wonder why.

Comment: Why was my comment removed? I advised OP to try first and then ask for further help with the photo as support, and seeing how the comment gathered some votes I don't see why it was necessary to have it removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fruit are very fascinating subjects as witnessed by the staggering number of still life paintings trying to catch their essence.  What makes them occur so much in paintings?

- color: fruit have rather intense and saturated colors.
- shape: they have particular shape, often smooth that responds in a very fine way to the way the light happens to fall.  In contrast to a typical painting, a photographer might work out depth to some degree by working with depth of field.
- lighting: It's not unusual that a still life contains a streak of light across fruit that put lit and shadow behavior right next to each other.  If you want to copy that particular approach, you'll have different light dominance in different parts of the image (sunlight vs fill-in flash?) and might have to work with gels in order to get a consistent white balance.
- function: fruit have a variety of parts, partly for reproduction, partly for attracting consumers (as consumption by animals is a typical seed distribution mechanism) with their own colors and shapes.
- inherent attractivity: humans eat fruit, so exposing their mouth-watering features is important.

Here are two examples (quality downgraded to match the site, sigh).  One just works via the color angle.  This bowl was actually not intended for photography but happened to trigger my camera finger: if this was supposed to be arranged, the bananas are completely borked, shown from their worst side (the stump) and badly lit.  All fruit would want polishing (in particular the cucumbers).  The out-of-camera JPEG appears a bit oversharpened as some of the fruit edges seem to have a slight halo (had this been saved RAW, one could have properly balanced it since the sharp edges are actually characteristic for that photograph; but if the edge starts ringing, it looks like an unwanted artifact).  This image mostly lives from the bell peppers and their colors, and the choice of a "vivid" color setting should be an obvious one to make.  There is very little shade and shapes are mostly apparent through highlighting: an obvious consequence of on-camera flash lighting.[image: Fruit bowl]

In comparison, here is a walnut[image: Walnut] (not technically fruit but photographically posing similar problems) where more care has been spent on creating a more complex lighting situation and filling in lots of detail.  Being processed in raw, it was possible to balance the interest of noise against detail level.

Here the focus is on shape (using comparatively small depth of focus for depth), function, detail.  Lighting is used for providing an untypical context, more usual for jewelry displays and slightly supported by shifting background, white balance and color representation into much less colorful terrain.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a question of camera techniques.

Fruit by itself is just boring. An interesting picture tells a story, camera techniques are just a means to do that effectively.

So think of ways you can tell a story with fruit. The most easy and straightforward way would be to make the fruit represent something else by arranging it in a certain way. Or you could put it in an unusual environment. Or use unusual lighting, or perspective.

Basically whatever makes people think "What's happening there?" rather than "OK, some fruit lying around, so what?".